# Calling a function on details.php - PyroCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Is there a way to call a function that is withing the `details.php` file from an admin controller from my custom module ?

Im developing a module that has sub modules within it.

Inside the `details.php` file there is the standard

install() function however I also have

```
install_module_a()
```

and

```
install_module_b()
```

So from my controller I would like to do something like

```
class Module_manager extends Admin_controller
{

    public function index() {}
    public function install_mod_a()
    {
       $this->details->install_module_a();

    }

}
```

PyroCMS version 2.2.x

also posted this question [here](https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/25115/calling-a-function-within-details-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to answer this question on https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/25115/calling-a-function-within-details-php

The answer is basically:

1. include the details.php
2. instantiate the class
3. call the function

The only more problematic thing is, to determine wether your modules are in the shared_addons/modules or addons/modules folder. But a simple is_file or file_exists check should help with that.

Check out installer/libraries/Module_import.php around line 76 and 222 to see how the PyroCMS team tackled this matter.

Comment: I have not tried this solution however the logic is correct, I was hopeing there was an already loaded details_file object. Although I didnt end up doing this, the way I solved my problem was by moving the install logic to another controller that manages the addon modules